# Where to find Spring WebSocket integration test artifact?

Tags: java, spring-websocket

I'm trying to setup a test for testing a Spring WebSocket client. I found this question which seemed interesting: [How to unit test Spring WebSocketStompClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734311/how-to-unit-test-spring-websocketstompclient)
However, I am unable to find the Spring artifact that contains the TomcatWebSocketTestServer class.
The source is in the Spring websocket repository, but I can't find any Maven coordinates for it?

Comment: Since this is part of their own unit tests there is a good chance it isn't published to Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mark pointed out, the codebase containing the source for the `TomcatWebSocketTestServer` is under the standard maven test source path so is unlikely to be published anywhere. However, the source code can be viewed in [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/78d1591e2ddfe01f05b9d09e68a00e7ad54c885a/spring-websocket/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/socket) along with the source code for other web socket test servers.

Hopefully this should give you a guide to what you would need to implement yourself for this to work.

EDIT: I know SO guidelines suggest posting code snippets rather than links, however this Spring Framework repo is unlikely to be removed anytime soon and the source is also (obviously) copyright protected and I did not want to post a copy, or snippets of it here.